# Selenium Webdriver + Protractor + CucumberJS

Tags: automation, webdriver, protractor, cucumberjs, webdriver-io

**Hello All**

I've discovered an issues, which I'm not sure it really is an known issue with the framework or it's due to the versions of Protractor + CucumberJS that I am using, these are:

```
"cucumber": "~0.7.0",
"protractor": "~2.5.1",
"selenium-standalone": "3.0.0",
```

I'm using this versions as of today, I know that CucumberJS was separate from Protractor, but since our current project is using Node < 4, I cannot update it.
Having said this, the error that I'm having is when I run the test suite with protractor `config.js` and the `seleniumAddress` attribute commented (it starts up a webdriver automatically at random port)
The error that appears, when the suite finishes is:

```
 throw new Error('This driver instance does not have a valid session ID ' +
        ^
```

***BUT*** when I run the exact same suite, starting webdriver manually and setting the selenium address, the test **passes**!!!

The suite contains:

```
17 scenarios (17 passed)
55 steps (55 passed)
```

Does anyone knows what could be the reason? My first thought is that starting the server manually it would make webDriver slower, and therefore test actions would be too, so... but I had compared both time executions and there's only 1 second difference between both....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had realized, that the problem with all is that since I had commented out the `seleniumAddress` line, Protractor was starting up webDriber-manager automatically, and when I added the line and manually started WebDriver, the error did not happen again. NOT sure what's the matter with it starting up automatically but, in case you ran into the same problem here's the solution!

Thanks